# emacs' org-cdlatex-mode, where do you put the cdlatex.el script?

Tags: windows, mode, emacs24

Does anyone know where to put the **cdlatex.el** script written by C. Dominik to allow swift LaTeX math insertion within an *.org file? CDLatex is a minor mode that can work with Org-mode, at least that's what I gather.

I've followed the instructions given [[in this link]](http://orgmode.org/manual/CDLaTeX-mode.html) but when I type `M-x org-cdlatex-mode RET` I get *"Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, cdlatex"* in the Emacs' echo buffer. What does it mean? I've also tried looking for a package named "cdlatex" in the list of packages (`M-x list-packages`) but there wasn't any. How do I get this **minor mode** activated in Org?

I'm running Windows 7, Emacs 24.1, Org-mode 8.2.10, AUCTEX 11.88, TexLive 2015. At least another user has this same problem, please check [this address](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19614/org-cdlatex-doesnt-work).

My emacs working path file is `C:\home\.emacs.d\`. Do I put the script in `C:\home\.emacs.d\elpa\`? Inside the `~\.emacs.d\elpa\` I also have yasnippets and auctex directories, among others. Here's a snapshot:[image: where do I put cdlatex.el?]

Answer (score 0):

Put the *cdlatex.el* script in one of the Load paths. To find all the load paths type `C-h v RET load-path RET`, then pick one and place the script in there. Restart emacs (or the machine if you prefer) and try out the CDLaTeX mode in one of the *.org files by enabling it either through menu or keyboard command:`M-x org-cdlatex-mode RET`.

Unfortunately for me there's some configuration problem because every time I type backquote or backtick (`), Org doesn't seem to recognize it when in CDLaTeX mode. It says: "Wrong type argument: characterp, 134217782"